# How do I get a static IP for my home router?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I don't know much about networking. I need to work remotely. My company will NOT give me a VPN. Instead, they want me to use a static IP which they will white list. So, I thought I'll use a static IP for my Netgear router as mentioned [here](http://kb.netgear.com/20486/How-to-enter-a-static-IP-address-on-a-NETGEAR-Router?cid=wmt_netgear_organic). It worked fine for one day & after that, devices were not able to connect to the internet. When I switched back to dynamic IPs, the problem was solved. The other option is to get a business internet account for my ISP. But, I don't want to get that because I'll have to pay for it.

How can I get a reliable static IP for home which I can use for work ?

Similar posts on the internet:
http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1780674/static-service-isp.html

Comment: Speak to the Admin of your company to sort this out.

Comment: @Xavierjazz - The admin does not want to do VPNs. Is there any reliable way I could solve this problem myself ?

Comment: So are you trying to bypass your company's policy?

Comment: @Xavierjazz - No, I am not. Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to comply by getting a reliable static IP myself.

Comment: Maybe the server could whitelist a hostname with your ip using dynamicdns ?

Comment: GiaRui - Can you please tell me how I can do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What they would whitelist is your Internet (aka public) IP address. However, *you can’t control that*. To get a fixed IP address, you’d need a business Internet subscription, which is usually a lot more expensive.

So if you **must** work remotely, your company **will** give you VPN access – or your dismissal. It’s really as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I know I should be asking the admin this question, but do you see any reason why someone would want to use IP whitelisting instead of VPN ? AFAIK, all companies use VPN.

Comment: No, using only whitelisting is idiotic. It’s easier to set up, but insecure. VPN (or maybe SSH tunneling) is the way to go. If the admin can’t be bothered to set it up and management lets him roll like that, you should get a new job.

Comment: I understand. I can't get a new job though and I need remote access quickly :) . I was hoping to make a strong case for VPN. Could you please point me to any links which show why IP white listing is bad and how VPN can help ? Thanks.

Comment: The other alternate is they pay for you to get business grade internet connection (i.e. with a static IP)

Comment: @networkdummy The problem with this whole situation is your position. Your opponent is an admin that’s against universally(!) accepted practices like VPN. He’s probably been employed a lot longer than you. Management apparently doesn’t care or understand. This isn’t really something anyone would discuss, ever, so there are no ready-to-use arguments. IP whitelisting is simply not suitable for “road warriors”, so nobody in their right mind would use it for that. Setting up OpenVPN can be done in a few hours. Maybe suggest that. Or really, just give up, it’s probably not going to happen.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - I'll have to pay for that and that is why I don't want to do it.

Comment: @networkdummy, the point is that, unless you are willing to pay for it, getting a static IP address is completely out of your control.

Comment: Can we RDP into a system that has access to company networks ?

Comment: @networkdummy Yes, certainly. Any form of tunnel will do. However, that would probably also require a whitelist entry.

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to get an unchanging IP address:

## 1: Control the address

Addresses originate from IANA, part of ICANN.  IANA gives addresses to the RIRs.

The last time I looked into getting a block of IPv4 addresses from an RIR, there was a basic requirement of having two live Internet connections.  This was intended to make sure that address blocks are just given out to entities who have sufficient need for addresses.

Usually RIRs give addresses to ISPs.

## 2: Get an address from an ISP

This is the normal route for individuals.  Ask your ISP.  If your ISP wants to charge you more (and classify it as a business connection), that is a somewhat-common practice I've heard of before.  Either accept that offering, or seek elsewhere.  I've heard of ISPs providing static IP addresses for free, upon request.  I can distinctly remember of one example of such a company, local to where I live.  Whether you have such an option where you live may be a different story.  Check out the competition.

## 3: Use a static address provided by someone else

I have a friend who works at an ISP.  He set up a computer, and gave away accounts.  (Since then, we've been giving away accounts with far less frequency.)

If there is a computer out there with a static IP, and you can connect/VPN into that computer, then you may be able to send traffic from that computer's IP address, which your work could then whitelist.

To pursue this, I guess you may want to look up "free shell accounts".  And you may need to learn a bit about things like port forwarding, VPNs, using a command line (in a UNIX-based platform), etc.  (When I say VPN, I'm referring to using a VPN to the provider of the server you're using, which you then use to connect to work.  I'm not suggesting using a VPN to connect from anywhere directly to work, because that requires setup/cooperation from the IT at work.)

## Summary

For most professionals, option #2 is probably the most common way that is typically considered easiest.  Really, if you can find a nice ISP, there may not really be significant drawbacks to this method.

Comment: I have VPN for my office connection, but the IT department say that it is preferred if I also have a static IP to ensure stability on the connection. I pay a small fee to my ISP provider for this, but it is not really that much.

Answer (score 1):

He didn't say that it has to be an IPv4 address. You can get IPv6 addresses for free and use a tunnel. See https://tunnelbroker.net/, for example (Not sure if safe, I just found it). But still, he might not accept Ipv6 addresses.

In that case you could also rent one and use a tunnel or get it trough your ISP. In these cases you probably will have to pay more, but not nescessarily. Some ISPs might offer a static IP in a normal package for non-business internet subscriptions.

You should inform yourself and also talk to the guy in case you have to buy something in order to get the IP. I'm not an expert on this but a VPN network would add a security layer as its usually encrypted. Give it a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network

Answer (score -2):

**VPN** is the only reasonable solution imho.

That said, here is one more solution that needs no IT interventions or in cases extra money to your ISP and allows you to access it :

### Get a url address that always maps to the right IP

You can map your ever-changing home IP address to a [url address using your preferred DNS_hosting_service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hosting_service)

Say you choose 'foobar.com'. You ll need to either run on your home pc a program, or set your router so that every time your ip changes, the DNS_hosting_service is notified (each service typically provides a file you can download and run).

Then,
instead of using an ip to access your pc, you can find it using a cool name of your choice such as my_home.foobar.com.  my_home.foobar.com will always point to the id of your pc. As a side note, most of those services also provide VPN services if you pay.

This won't work if the admin only whitelists (numeric) IP address, not domain names and might not be a solution that should be used professionally in large companies. Also, it might include some security risks. (**You get what you pay for, and this is the only 'for free' way proposed.**)

Comment: This won't work if the admin only whitelists (numeric) IP address, not domain names.

Comment: @dirkt and it may not even be possible to use a hostname instead of an IP.  Hostnames can resolve to multiple IPs....

Comment: @dirkt You are right. (Assuming also the port of the home the service is not accessible). Nothing to do there... Added this to the answer.

Comment: @ivanivan True, hostnames can resolve to multiple IPs, so that can be a security risk. You get what you pay for, though IP addresses can be spoofed as well. On the other side, if I e.g. pay noip.com to map this_is_the_home.ddns.net to my IP address, I am assuming that they will make sure it is resolved correctly, since that is a major part of their buisness..